# retrieve id of table rows?

Tags: php, jquery

i have this script bellow to open table2 when clicking on the buttom 'more details'

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#Table1 tr').click(function(event){

         $('#Table2').show();
         alert($(this).attr('id'));
       });
     });

</script>
```

and this my code

```
 <table id= "Table1" width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    $sql2=..
    $sql3 = blabla ;
    while($row3 =mysql_fetch_array($sql3)){
    $sql4 = mysql_query (" SELECT $ww as place FROM data WHERE $ww =".$row3[$ww]." and  id_user = ".$userid." ");
    $row4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4) ;
    $string = "<blink > here  </blink>" ;

    $wnumber = $row3[$ww] ;

     echo "<tr id= '".$wnumber."'><td  style= 'text-align : center ;'>Week ".$row3[$ww]."
              </td>" ;
     echo "<td >".(int) $row3["percent"] ."% </td>";
     echo "<td > "?><?php if($row4['place'] == 
     $row3[$ww] and $row2['id'] == $userid ){ echo $string ; } else { echo "";} ;?><?php
     "</td>";
     echo "<td ><button class='showr'>More Details</button> </td></tr>";
    //More Details when clicking on this buttom it open the table2
     }
   </tr>
 </table>
```

this is second table

```
 <?php
    echo "<div id= 'Table2' style= 'display:none;'>";
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
    echo "<th> Week ".$wnumber."</th>";
    echo "<th>try2</th>";
    echo "<tr ><td>day</td>";
    echo "<td>fff</td></tr>";
    echo "</table></div>";
 ?>
```

*what i have now 5 rows with 5 buttoms . 
*what it happen now is when clicking on every bottom it echo same '$wnumber' lets say 6.
      however it defers from row to row ,
    - script works good with alert of the id of which row is clicked. 
   - only the last buttom who works with the last id of row.
*what i want is every bottom works with its row id which echo the right '$wnumber'
* what i have tried is (make variable in the div)

```
   echo "<div id= '".$wnumber."' style= 'display:none;'>";
```

instead of

```
    echo "<div id= 'Table2' style= 'display:none;'>";
```

but didnt work.

hope its clear and there is solution of it.

EDIT : this source code

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#Table1 tr').click(function(event){

     $('#Table2').show();
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
 });

  </script>

  <br />
  <table id= "Table1" width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <th >Weeks</th>
 <th ><p></p></th>

 <th > Your place</th>
 <th > More Details</th>
<tr>
 <tr id= '1'><td  style= 'text-align : center ;'>Week 1</td><td style= 'text-align : 
  center ;'>33% </td><td  style= 'text-align : center ;'> <td style= 'text-align :  
  center ;'><button class='showr'>More Details</button></td></tr><tr id= '6'><td   
  style= 'text-align : center ;'>Week 6</td><td style= 'text-align : center ;'>33%   
  </td><td  style= 'text-align : center ;'> <td style= 'text-align : center   
  ;'><button  
  class='showr'>More Details</button></td></tr><tr id= '13'><td  style= 'text-align:   
  center ;'>Week 13</td><td style= 'text-align : center ;'>33% </td><td  style=   
  'text-align : center ;'> <blink style= 'color:#990000 ;font-weight: bolder;' >  69   
  here </blink><td style= 'text-align : center ;'><button class='showr'>More   
  Details</button></td></tr></tr>

 </table>
 <br />
 <div id= 'Table2' style= 'display:none;'><table width='100%' border='1'  
  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><th> Week 13</th><th>try2</th><tr ><td>day</td>  
  <td>fff</td></tr></table></div>
  <br /><br /> <br />
```

Comment: can you post the converted html from view source.

Comment: go to your webpage, right click, view source, then copy the required html and paste it here. If somebody wants to try out your code, having php in between your html will not be helpful

Comment: Your code works fine as far as I can tell, but I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your HTML's invalid; your `<th></th>` elements need to be wrapped in a `<tr></tr>`.

Comment: I think your PHP loop logic is faulty. You only have 1 row in Table2. If I understand correctly, you need to have the same number of rows in Table2 that you have in Table1. The code is very messy -- it'd be much easier to help if you cleaned up your PHP and HTML.

Comment: it works because the script alert the right id , but i want echo this id in the table2 as '$wnumber' so instead of this variable i want the id of the alerted one

Comment: if "it works", then no reason to post the question. If you'd like it to work -well-,  clean up the code. Trust me, from years of programming it's far easier to make things work well with decently formatted, clean code.

Comment: douglas , sorry for you dont understand. i said i dont want alert the id only. but echo it and show the related table by this id. you just read the first word and maybe you dont read all.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your html code after correcting the missing `td`, `tr`.
And then clicking on each row / button displays the `div`. 
Ensure you form proper html code in your php `echo`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Table1 tr').click(function(event){
            $('#details').find('#week' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
            // alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });

</script>
<?php

$result = mysql_query($sql);

// save the results to an array so you can loop them twice
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) :
    $rows[] = $row;
endwhile;

?>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>heading</th>
        <th>heading</th>
        <th>heading</th>
        <th>heading</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : // loop #1 to output the main table ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $row['ww'] ?>">
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td><button type="button">More details</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table> <!-- end table 1 -->

<div id="details">
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : // loop #2 to output a table for each set of details ?>
    <table id="week<?php echo $row['ww'] ?>" style="display: none">
        <tr>
            <th>Week <?php echo $row['ww'] ?></th>
            <th>try2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value</td>
            <td>value</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div> <!-- end details -->
```

Comment: you mean row3 instead of row ?

Comment: i dont know why '$row3[$ww]' is recognized in table1 and it comes with value but in table2 didnt recogniyed and it comes with no value.

Comment: You need 2 loops, that's the point of my code. I didn't use $row3, but if you want to use that, it's your call (though that variable name isn't very readable or semantic.

Comment: i have make all your code and i had to change the place 'endforeach;' of the second table after the '</div>' and changed row to row3 so everything looks good without erros but the script dont work , didnt show the table2 ,

Comment: The `endforeach;` should definitely be *before* the `</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I copy / pasted your code into a jsFiddle and it seems to work as expected. Clicking on the row sends an alert with the correct ID.

http://jsfiddle.net/JeeNN/

Is there something I'm missing in your intent here?

Note : Best practice would be to skip the inline CSS and add external styling for your tables. Also, valid HTML is a must.

---

Update:

I went ahead and formatted the php code you posted so it's a bit easier to read. There's some variables that aren't defined and a couple other issues, but I'm sure you have it correct in your php file.

I think that you're going to want to run the loop a second time to create the second table. In this second loop, echo out the second table once per loop - you'll end up with a bunch of tables (one per row plus the first table). Then simply swap the visibility of the tables as user's click each id.

Is that what you're looking for? If not, perhaps try to rephrase your question.

Here's that formatted code:

```
<table id="Table1" width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<?php
$sql2 = [..];
$sql3 = [..];
$ww = ?;

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)){

    $sql4 = mysql_query ("SELECT $ww as place FROM data WHERE $ww =".$row3[$ww]." and  id_user = ".$userid." ");
    $row4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4) ;
    $string = "<blink> here </blink>" ;

    $wnumber = $row3[$ww];

    echo "<tr id='".$wnumber."'>";
        echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>Week ".$row3[$ww]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".(int) $row3["percent"] ."% </td>";
        echo "<td>":
        if($row4['place'] == $row3[$ww] and $row2['id'] == $userid ){
            echo $string;
        } else {
            echo "&nbsp;";
        }
        echo "</td>";
        //More Details when clicking on this buttom it open the table2
        echo "<td ><button class='showr'>More Details</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} ?>
</table>

<div id= 'Table2' style= 'display:none;'>
    <table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr>
            <th> Week <?php echo $wnumber; ?></th>
            <th>try2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>day</td>
            <td>fff</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i said it alert the right id , but i want echo this id in the table2 as '$wnumber'

Comment: in your link as i see it doesnt show the table2 , it only alert the id

Comment: `echo` is a PHP command and renders when the page is created - `echo` cannot change out content per user click without a page refresh. What you want to do is use jQuery to change the `.text()` of table2. Looks like you'll need to add more `id` tags so you can easily swap the information. Here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/JeeNN/1/